# how to write method definition for the Product* getProductFromID(std::string);

Tags: c++, class, methods, definitions

Please tell me how to write definitions for the functions:

```
Product* getProductFromID(std::string);

void Store:: addMember(Customer* c)
```

addmember shud add the member details to the vector named cart
and i have tried something like this

```
void Store:: addMember(Customer* c)
{
    Customer c(std::string n, std::string a, bool pm);
    members.push_back(n.str());
}
```

I get an error saying `[Error] 'n' was not declared in this scope`.

Comment: Please post a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You declare variables as the parameters for the constructor of your `Customer c`. They should be declared outside, and given an initial value for good measure.

Comment: @Jonas If you just type MCVE in square brackets, you get a nicely formatted link: [MCVE].

Comment: @BoBTFish, wow, and I have been formatting it myself as an ordinary link for God knows how long... `[MCVE](link)`...

Comment: @Jonas thankyou i did that just now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
Customer c(std::string n, std::string a, bool pm);
```

declares a function `c` that takes three parameters and returns a `Customer`. Not what you want at all.

Assuming that a `Customer` contains an `n` member (which really needs a more descriptive name), the function would just look like

```
void Store:: addMember(Customer* c)
{
    members.push_back(c->n.str());
}
```

Comment: i did as u said thanks for suggesting
now the code is in this manner
`void Store:: addMember(Customer* c) 
{
 members.push_back(c->name.str());
 }`
and i am getting an error saying 
 [Error] 'std::string Customer::name' is private

Comment: i got it with a function through which i accessed the variable thankyou @Bo Persson